# Does symmetry of $AB$ imply symmetry of $A^\dagger B^T$

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, pseudoinverse

Let $A$ and $B$ not necessarily symmetric but $AB$ symmetric. Is $A^\dagger B^T$ also symmetric i.e.
\begin{equation}
A^\dagger B^T = B (A^\dagger)^T
\end{equation}
where $A^\dagger$ is the pseudo inverse of $A$?

I asked a particular case of this question when $A$ and $B$ are symmetric ([Does symmetry of $AB$ implies symmetry of $A^\dagger B$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4457483/1025314)) and I am wondering if it still holds when $A$ and $B$ are non-symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

I found a counter-example : let $A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then we have $AB = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, indeed symmetric, yet, $A^\dagger B^T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ which is not symmetric.